# Aggregate grid cells to larger resolution in sf

Tags: r, grid, r-sf

Consider a grid cell, where each cell is 10x10.

```r
library(sf)
grid1 <- st_make_grid()

plot(grid1)
```

[image]

**I would like to create another grid cell, based on `grid1`, where each cell is 30x30 and consists of 9 10x10 neighboring cells.**

I have very few clues as to how to do it, but I'd rather prefer an `sf` solution. I've tried with `st_buffer`, but it creates a buffer around each cell. One could perhaps group neighboring cells and aggregate them, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Have you looked into the arguments of `st_make_grid()`?

Comment: Not enough apparently, but now I got it. Will post as answer. Thanks for the nudge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `st_make_grid`'s `cellsize` parameter, one can make a grid from an existing one and choose the resolution. Using a cellsize of 30 will indeed group the 8 neighboring cells.

```r
grid2 <- st_make_grid(grid1, cellsize = 30)

plot(grid2, lwd = 3)
plot(grid1, add = TRUE, col = NA)
```

[image]

---

Note that this works because the grid is made of squares; `st_make_grid` might not recover the neighboring elements if they are not squares.